# Light weight Linux operating system

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Can any one please tell me a light weight Linux kernel which supports the kexec functionality, and takes minimum time to boot.
I am using the kexec functionality that is already present in Linux distros like REd hat Enterprise Edition, but i want to shift to a light weight Linux kernel.

Comment: please let me know asap

Comment: I think it is off topic question...You must ask this on askubuntu!!

Comment: What is lightweight per your needs ?

Comment: Just compile your own [kernel](http://kernel.org/) (maybe using `make-kpkg`). Or are you after a lightweight [Linux distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)?

Comment: yes actually i m looking for a light  weight linux distribution .... as kernel compilation would be little erroneous and hectic. so i would like to rather stick with some already linux  distribution

Comment: please suggest me if there are any linux distributions which supports kexec functionality

Answer (score 3):

Get sources of linux kernel from kernel.org and compile your own one with some disabled features(filesystem supports, schedulars and governors,..) , drivers and debugging functions(printk,...) then enable `CONFIG_KEXEC` in .config.

Comment: Maybe even try working from the other direction. Run `make allnoconfig` then enable the functions you need.

Comment: Some config are needed to boot the kernel so I think allnoconfig is not so good.

Comment: Yeah, so just enable the options needed to boot after running allnoconfig

Answer (score -3):

kexec works only on PDA, Not on Computer Server or Desktop

Comment: No, `kexec` can work on a kernel that you have compiled....

Comment: but you need to modify the kernel parameter for making it work, but still its isn’t reliable.